# IBM Watson chat bot

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, watson-conversation

I am currently working on Watson chat bot with the aim of creating a virtual assistant for customers which hopefully will be capable of handling the requests. Within a node I ask a question like "Can you provide me the serial number?" to the customer. What I want Watson to do is that save that serial number as a variable so that I can respond the customer like "Okay so the number you provided is **"that number"**, do you confirm?" I would be very happy if someone can help me out with this. How am I going to integrate a variable capable of storing the customer´s input?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend starting with this [tutorial on building a database-driven Slack chatbot](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html). The source code is available on GitHub.

The tutorial shows how to gather event data. The typical way of getting data from an user is to save the relevant parts in so-called [context variables](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/expression-language.html#shorthand-context). You can access those variables from within dialog nodes, print values in responses or pass them to other code for backend processing (like in a database system).

Comment: Oh thank you Henrik, this is really helpful. Would you be able to help me if I can send you some screenshots from my Watson bot? There is one part I am stuck at.

Comment: I would recommend joining this public Slack to discuss it interactively: http://wdc-slack-inviter.mybluemix.net/
Please mark this question as answered if it helped. Ask a new question for a new topic. :)